# How to remove &nbsp; from a UTF-8 string?

Tags: php, utf-8, html-entities

My database is returning some strings like:

`This&nbsp;is&nbsp;a&nbsp;string`

This is a problem when the string is long enough and you have maximum width set:

```
<p style="width:50px">This&nbsp;is&nbsp;a&nbsp;string</p>
```

In order to get ride of `&nbsp;` entities I've tried to use the following filters without success:

```
$new = preg_replace("/&nbsp;/i", " ", $str);
$new = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $str);
$new = html_entity_decode($str);
```

You have a [PHP fiddle to see this in action](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/egs0-rf4n) (I've had to codify the string in hex from the database output; the string is in spanish, sorry).

How to deal with this? Why `html_entity_decode()` is not working? And what about the replace functions? Thanks.

Comment: `html_entity_decode` works. Trouble is, you don't want non-breaking spaces, but normal spaces.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This gets tricky, its not as straight forward as replacing normal string.

Try this.

```
 str_replace("\xc2\xa0",' ',$str);
```

or this, the above should work:

```
$nbsp = html_entity_decode("&nbsp;");
$s = html_entity_decode("[&nbsp;]");
$s = str_replace($nbsp, " ", $s);
echo $s;
```

@ref: https://moovwebconfluence.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1081435

Comment: only this line worked for me: `$s = str_replace($nbsp, "", $s);`

Answer (score 3):

Get the html entities replace the one you want and decode back:

```
$str = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', htmlentities($new));
$new = html_entity_decode($str);
```