# woocommerce remove &nbsp; before string

Tags: php, woocommerce

I try to get product variation meta data and my string contains thes html entity spaces `&nbsp;`

My code:

```
$_alusM2 = get_post_meta($product_id, '_alus_al', true);
```

It should give me `_alus_al` field text and it looks like this: `8,6 m2 / 224 tk / 1350 kg` but I see many `&nbsp;` before `8,6 m2`

I've tried this:

```
$content = str_replace('&nbsp;',"",$_alusM2);
$content = preg_replace( '/\s+/', '', $content );
```

but still same issue.

---

If I `var_dump($_alusM2);` then it says `string(25)` so it is OK but why it gives so many white spaces `&nbsp;` with echo?

Comment: Make a debug output of `urlencode($_alusM2)` - the resulting percent encoding is an easy way to see which byte values you actually have in your string.

Comment: Look at these answers: [How to remove &nbsp; from a UTF-8 string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28704562/how-to-remove-nbsp-from-a-utf-8-string) and [replace &nbsp; characters that are hidden in text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870974/replace-nbsp-characters-that-are-hidden-in-text)